# will my files still remain after OS replace install option?

Tags: system, install-from-source

I'd like to try the replace OS option of install....can my files (downloads etc) etc remain intact with this option post installation?

Comment: Probably.  There is a possibility that during the replacement of the OS, something will not go correctly, and you should try to make a backup of your files.

Comment: Which OS are you replacing?

Answer (score 0):

It normally keep intact all your home folder but replace all the system. But, if there is a problem during install (Hardware problem), there is a possibility that you loose all your data. So make a backup of the most important things that you have.